# Webform Conditional auto un-select

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using Webform 7.x-4.0-alpha6.

I have configured a number of radio options in a "parent" component. When each of the radio buttons are selected, different "child" components showup. Each child is unique to each radio button in the parent. Like the following:

parent => 
radio#1
radio#2
radio#3

child=> [radio#1]
radio#1-option#1
radio#1-option#2
radio#1-option#3

child=> [radio#2]
radio#2-option#1
radio#2-option#2

child=> [radio#3]
radio#3-option#1
radio#3-option#2
radio#3-option#3
radio#3-option#4

**What I am trying to achieve is allowing no more than one option to be selected across all the lists of radio buttons.**

So, if I select **radio#1-option#1** under **parent=>radio#1** and I happen to change my mind and select **radio#3=>option#4** under **parent=>radio#3**, I want **radio#1-option#1** to be automatically deselected/unset.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Webform Conditional module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional), this has some extended conditional rule on radio button and other form elements:

> Webform already has support for conditional fields on multi-page forms. For example Field C on Page 2 can be dependent on Field A on Page 1. This module adds the ability to have conditional fields on the same page. This module adds the ability to have Field B on page 1 be dependent on Field A also on Page 1.